# dojo store memory: the data is being updated before using the put() call.?

Tags: dojo

Dojo tookit version: 1.9.3 
I have started learning dojo/store/memory from here.
https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/intro_dojo_store/

I tried to run the example in the tutorial with some modification.
Ran the get() **(var oldjim = employeeStore.get("Jim");)** call to check the value in the memory store before making a put() call.
I can see that the data has already been changed.

```
    // retrieve object with the name "Jim"
    var jim = employeeStore.get("Jim");
    // show the department property
    console.log("Jim's department is " + jim.department);
    // iterate through all the properties of jim:
    for(var i in jim){
        console.log(i, "=", jim[i]);
    }
    // update his department
    jim.department = "engineering";

    // START *** Modified code
    // Get the old data for "jim"
    var oldjim = employeeStore.get("Jim");
    // Displays the OLD data before making a put() call to the store.
    console.log("oldJim's department is " + oldjim.department); 
    // output "oldJim's department is engineering"
    // END *** Modified code

    // and store the change
    employeeStore.put(jim);
```

Is this the behaviour of the dojo/store/memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more behaviour of JavaScript than `dojo/store/Memory`.

Have a look at the implementation of [`dojo/store/Memory::get(id)`](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/store/Memory.js#L41) method. It returns an object stored in `data` property array. In JavaScript objects are passed by reference and that means `jim` and `oldjim` both points to the same place in the memory. You can easily check it ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/2xwW9/)):

```
console.log(jim === oldjim);  // true
```

To avoid this behaviour you can modify `dojo/store/Memory` class so it returns a copy (clone) of the object:

```
require(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang", "dojo/store/Memory"], function(declare, lang, Memory){

        var ModifiedMemory = declare(Memory, {
            get: function(id) {
                return lang.clone(this.data[this.index[id]]);
            }
        });

});
```

In this case (using `ModifiedMemory` instead of `Memory`), `jim === oldjim` will evaluate to `false`, because they're not the same object anymore (i.e. there are 2 copies in the memory now) and therefore `dojo/store/Memory::put()` will work as you expect it to work.

See `ModifiedMemory` class in action at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/G5Gc6/).

Comment: @martin.. Appreciate ur effort taken to answer the query. Thanks. I would expect to return another object instead of a reference to the object. This could create issues if one manipulates the store directly without using the APIs (put call).